# Display different elements based on even and odd in Django HTML template

Tags: python, html, django, templates, jinja2

I am new to Django. And I faced this problem:
dest over here is a list which is coming from file *views.py*.

I want to use this (code below) for even occurrences:

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-2 text-white showcase-img" style="background-image:url( {{baseUrl}}/{{dest.img}} );"><span></span></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 my-auto order-lg-1 showcase-text">
                        <h2> {{dest.name}} </h2>
                        <p class="lead mb-0">{{dest.desc}}</p>
                        The Price : <p class="lead mb-0" style="font-weight:bold">Rs. {{dest.price}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And this (code below) for odd positions:

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-lg-6 text-white showcase-img" style="background-image:url(&quot;{% static 'img/bg-showcase-2.jpg' %}&quot;);"><span></span></div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 my-auto order-lg-1 showcase-text">
                    <h2>Updated For Bootstrap 4</h2>
                    <p class="lead mb-0">Newly improved, and full of great utility classes, Bootstrap 4 is leading the way in mobile responsive web development! All of the themes are now using Bootstrap 4!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get {{dest.name}}, unless you iterate over it in a **for loop** (because dest is a list as you mentioned).

Also, it is not clear what is the occurrence you are counting on, so I'll just mention it as "occurrence" in the code, and you can replace it with your variable. **If** it is the number of loops that you're using then you can use
**{{ forloop.counter }}**

```
{% for val in dest %}
    {%if occurence|divisibleby:2 %}
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-2 text-white showcase-img" style="background-image:url( {{baseUrl}}/{{val.img}} );"><span></span></div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 my-auto order-lg-1 showcase-text">
                    <h2> {{val.name}} </h2>
                    <p class="lead mb-0">{{val.desc}}</p>
                    The Price : <p class="lead mb-0" style="font-weight:bold">Rs. {{val.price}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-lg-6 text-white showcase-img" style="background-image:url(&quot;{% static 'img/bg-showcase-2.jpg' %}&quot;);"><span></span></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 my-auto order-lg-1 showcase-text">
                <h2>Updated For Bootstrap 4</h2>
                <p class="lead mb-0">Newly improved, and full of great utility classes, Bootstrap 4 is leading the way in mobile responsive web development! All of the themes are now using Bootstrap 4!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```